# Laravel 7 redirect away shows redirect url on white page

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5, laravel-7

I am redirecting away from Laravel 7 controller and it shows the redirection url just before it redirects to the url. I am using the following code:

```
private function createPayment($session_token)
{
    ...

    try {
        $response = Http::timeout(30)->withHeaders($headers)->post($url, $body)->json();

        if ($response['statusCode'] != '0000') {
            $this->redirectError($response['statusCode'], $session_token);
        }

        $url= $response['bkashURL'];

        redirect()->away($url)->send();
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $this->redirectError($response['statusCode'], $session_token);
    }
}
```

// redirect error method:

```
private function redirectError($code, $session_token = null)
{
    if ($session_token != null) {
        session()->forget($session_token);
    }

    $message = $this->error($code);

    $url = config('global.api_url_bkash') . 'error/' . $message;

    redirect()->away($url)->send();
}
```

// error method:

```
private function error($code)
{
    switch ($code) {
        case '2001':
            return 'Invalid App Key';
            break;

        case '2002':
            return 'Invalid Payment ID';
            break;
            
    .....
}
```

I getting this :

[image]

how can I prevent the page not to show the url.

Comment: Where is  your code? In controller?

Comment: why are you calling `send`? just return the response, the framework handles converting it into the appropriate response

Comment: you are not 'returning' anything here

Comment: Please show your `redirectError()` function

Comment: yes, i need to redirect away without returning anything. this code working. only issue is it shows the urls for few seconds before it redirect away. @lagbox

Comment: you need to return a response somewhere ... something must be calling this private method ... in the code above you are creating a redirect response and doing nothing with it

Comment: @jewishmoses check the edited question.

Comment: I tried with return statement at the first place like this :  ``redirect()->away($url)->send();`` but as the urls were appearing I removed the return statement.

Comment: **STOP** calling `send` there is no reason for you to call that method ... laravel handles the responses and the headers ... you need to **return** the responses

Comment: @lagbox when I stop calling the send method it shows a blank page and redirects no where. with and without return satement.

Comment: there is a call stack in place ...every function call or method call adds to this stack, you then need to pass things back through the stack (via return statements) to unwind it, and you are not doing this ... you need to return these responses from every place until it gets back to the controller then you need to return the response from there ... there is no magic happening here

Comment: ok I followed your suggestion and its working now without send(). but still It shows the urls before loads the page. @lagbox

Comment: redirect responses have headers for the redirect, they also have a body that explains a redirect is happening and a meta refresh to make you go there if the browser does not do the redirect based on the headers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219427/discussion-between-wahidsherief-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `send` method, just return Response object from controller method.

```php
public function index()
{
    // ...
    $url = config('global.api_url');
    
    return redirect()->away($url);
}
```

Comment: have tried without send but it doesnt work. u might check my edited question. @zlodes

Comment: Where is the `createPayment` method? I think it is not a controller method (because it is private).

Or you call it from other controller method. In that case you should return `url` from the `createPayment` and return `redirect()->away($url)` in your target controller method.

You need return response object from the method referenced in routes list.

Comment: `redirect()->away('...')->send()` does work even if it's not best practice

Comment: I tried with return statement at the first place like this :  ``redirect()->away($url)->send();`` but as the urls were appearing I removed the return statement. I have public methods but i have some private method where the method is doing some calculations in the same controller.

Comment: 1. Remove `send()` call. 2. Add return statement in your private method (for try and catch blocks). 3. Add return statement in your public method.

Comment: @zlodes did all but same result. urls are showing just before redirecting.